# Making a map using google maps in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I am trying to create a map in node.js by calling my javascript file to do it for me.

```
require('./js/file.js')();
initMap();
```

This didn't work, as it gave me an error that "google was undefined" in my initMap() function. So, I tried to require the api script itself:

```
require('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places')();
require('./public/js/graphs.js')();
initMap();
```

which also, unsurprisingly, didn't work. How can I fix this? I tried loading in the map api inside the javascript file itself, but that required jquery, which also wasn't defined either, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize the Google Maps JS which is designed for Browsers, not for Node, so that's why you get a "undefined" response.

I made this work by using PhantomJS; You create a "html template" where you have your map, initialize the map, then draw whatever you have to draw, and you can save it as PDF/Image with PhantomJS.

There is an example:

The "PhantomJS Script"

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var fs        = require('fs');

page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4',
  orientation: 'portrait',
  margin: '0mm'
};   

var path      = args[1];
var code  = args[2];

page.open(path + '/imageMap.html', function(status) {
  page.dpi = 96.0;
  status = status.trim();
  console.log(status);
  if(status === "success") {
    var title = page.evaluate(function(code) {
      window.generateMap(code);
      return true;
    }, code);

    setTimeout(function(){
      page.render(path + '/img/' + code + '.png');
      phantom.exit();
    }, 1500);

  }else{
    phantom.exit(1);
  }

});
```

As you can see, i give a 1500ms in the setTimeout, its just to make sure that the map was loaded and finished drawing (maybe there's a better way, but, it works)

And your imageMap.html is whatever you are doing with GMaps, like using the sample file from the docs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0px;
        paddin:0px;
      }
      #map_canvas{
        width:600px;
        height: 445px;
      }
      .gm-style-cc {
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery and other front end libraries don't work the same in nodejs.  You'll want to look into a nodejs client for the google maps API.

[This one](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) is provided by google.